# JavaScript validation - document.getElementById not working in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an `onSubmit()` function to validate form entries.

The form and validation function work OK,if the form is in a standalone php file or an html file.

But when the form is embedded in a Bootstrap modal the JS validation function throws an error message. `[object HTMLInputElement]`

I have tried changing `document.getElementById('uemail')` to `document.getElementById('uemail').value` as recommended in another answer, 
but no value has apparently been passed to the function.

If I remove the `onSubmit()` attribute then the values are passed correctly to the action script on the server.

This must be common usage. What am I doing wrong?

This is an abbreviated section of my code:

```
<script>
function formCheck() {
    var valid = true;
    //alert('in function');
    var email = document.getElementById('uemail');
    alert('email:' + email);
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(email)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus;
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
</script>


<form id="regform" action="action.php" method="post" onSubmit="return formCheck()">
    Email: <input type="text" name="uemail" id="uemail" size="50" value="" required><span id ="ast">*</span><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** looks like you can't do `document.getElementById`, you can do this instead:

```
function formCheck(formEl) {
    //...
    var email = formEl.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    // this will get the first input-element in your form
```

and

```
onsubmit="return formCheck(this)"
```

---

**Mistake:** The variable `email` you are testing is a HTMLElement, not a string:

[image]

**Solution:** set `email` to the value of the HTMLInputElement:

```
var email = document.getElementById('uemail').value;
```

also `email.focus;` is not doing anything, use `email.focus();`

**Demo:**

```js
function formCheck() {
  var valid = true;
  //alert('in function');
  var email = document.getElementById('uemail').value;
  alert('email:' + email);
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (!filter.test(email)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
}
```

```html
<form id="regform" action="action.php" method="post" onsubmit="alert(formCheck())">
  Email:
  <input type="text" name="uemail" id="uemail" size="50" value="" required><span id="ast">*</span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I try to extract the value of the element, using getElementById().value there does not seem to be a value.

Comment: The code with .value does work perfectly, until it is run from within a modal. That is my problem.

Comment: I am afraid not. Code will still not work inside the modal.

Comment: well then I did my best, sorry. But maybe give it a up for the partialy correct solution and the effort I put in

Comment: Thanks getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value solves my problem. Sorry about the delay in responding but I have now applied it to the complete form, with success. Thanks again - a great response to my first ever on-line request for help.

Comment: Great! It's never easy to be clear when formulating a question, but you have to start somewhere ;)